# GAE redirect inside try throws exception

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

A simple logout redirect handler.

```
    logging.info(users.create_logout_url(self.request.get('return_url')))
    try:
        return self.redirect(users.create_logout_url(self.request.get('return_url')), abort=True)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Could not Logout user')
        logging.error(repr(e))
        #self.redirect('/')
        return
    #self.redirect('/')
```

This fails with exception of  < HTTPFound at 0xca3e60 302 Moved Temporarily >

if I move the redirect outside the try works.

I am confused.

Comment: without abort=true works. Why this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling with abort=True causes `HTTPFound` to be raised, which is an `Exception`. If you're worried about create_logout_url erroring, then wrap that with `try ... except` separately.

Comment: Thanks. It is what I needed. I didn't know that it raises the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from the documentation:

> This won’t stop code execution unless abort is True. A common practice is to return when calling this method:

```
return redirect('/some-path')
```

For more details, take a look at [webapp2.redirect](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.redirect).

Comment: I edited the question. Returning does not help my issue. Still when I wrap it inside a try, it throws the same exception.